# Eclipse unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, keystore

I am attempting to send an email via smtp to smtp.mailgun.org. I am not concerned about the java code that is attempting to send the email.

**Environment:**

> Windows 10   Eclipse Photon  Java 1.8.0_191  java package:
>   com.sun.mail.javax.mail:1.6.2

I am trying to send through 587 using TLS. I don't have much experience creating or modifying keystores.

In the `eclipse.ini`, I added the following two arguments after the -vmargs

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/lib/security/cacerts "

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="password"
```

I restarted Eclipse and am continuing to get the error below.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
      nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1652)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:534)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at com.mako.mg.manager.MakoMailGunSmtpManager.sendEmail(MakoMailGunSmtpManager.java:158)
        at com.mako.mg.manager.MakoMailGunSmtpManager.main(MakoMailGunSmtpManager.java:180)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:503)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:443)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1647)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
```

Is my Eclipse having a problem using the cacerts? or do I need to create a keystore from the cacerts?

I cannot find `c:\users\<myuser>\.keystore`. I am configured to view hidden files and folders.

Thank you for your help with this issue.

Comment: You don't usually need to specify `cacerts` store. Post your code. Do you have a work proxy that has SSL termination? If you do, then you need to add your proxy's certificate into cacerts (or specify a separate store).

Answer (score 1):

I added **-Djavax.net.debug=ssl** and looked through the steps prior to the failure. I found that my anti-virus was getting in the way and causing the failure. Turned off the anti-virus for testing and the email was sent successfully.

Found on AVG's site a link with the following steps

> open AVG Antivirus, click on Menu->Settings->Components->Email
>   Scanner->Customize. On the next window under 'Main Settings', please
>   disable "scan outbound email" and let us know if that resolves the
>   issue.